# JIRA's “SafePluginPointAccess” reporting my plugin is producing a NullPointerException—how do I get at the stack trace?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jira, jira-plugin

I'm trying to build a custom field type for JIRA, but whenever I add my field to an issue, JIRA says the following:

> The field was added successfully, but you do not have edit permissions.

However, in the stdout of `atlas-run`, I get the following line:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2017-04-24 09:31:20,813 http-nio-2990-exec-11 WARN adam 571x584x2 fgpziy 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 /secure/AjaxIssueEditAction!default.jspa [c.atlassian.ozymandias.SafePluginPointAccess] Unable to run plugin code because of 'java.lang.NullPointerException - null'.
```

In `target/jira/home/log/atlassian-jira.log` I can see exactly the same thing; both have that one-line error message and nothing else.

Is there anywhere I can go to find a stacktrace for the `NullPointerException` that's being reported here, so I can tell which bit of my code it's coming from?

I've tried running `atlas-run --jvmargs -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow`, but I still get the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a JIRA version before 7.2, it could be related to [this issue](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/nullpointerexception-when-creating-issue-editing-issue-move-issue-accessing-the-screen-tab-from-the-project-296097082.html) which is a bug in JIRA itself.

To answer your question, you can use [the `atlas-debug` command](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/developer-tools/working-with-the-sdk/command-reference/atlas-debug), which lets you attach a Java remote debugging tool to JIRA.

Comment: I'm on 7.2 already, and it's not related to that bug, but `atlas-debug` let me see where the exception was coming from which was what I wanted, thanks!